# When POSTing a Django form, my changes to the form's data are lost

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In my Django app, I have a `page.html` that includes forms from multiple models like so:

```py
# models.py
class OneModel(models.Model):
    foo = models.CharField(...)
    bar = models.CharField(...)

# forms.py
class OneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = OneModel
```

On save, in addition to the POST data, I add a prefix to all the forms, for example:

```py
form1 = OneForm(prefix=OneForm.Meta.model._meta.module_name)
```

Then, I send the `POST` request to be saved and send the next data to the `__init__` form:

```py
# views.py
form_data = {'foo': 'fo-fo-fo',    # from request.POST
             'bar': 'bar-bar-bar'} # -//-//-
form1 = OneForm(form_data)         # without prefix
```

Afterwards, when the template is being put together, I get input from the form with my data (`fo-fo-fo`, `bar-bar-bar`), but without the prefix in input names, which is not what I want.

But if I add the prefix in the `__init__` part instead I get back the form without my data:

```py
# views.py
form1 = OpenForm(prefix=OneForm.Meta.model._meta.module_name, form_data)
```

How can I get the results of the form with *both* the data I need and the prefix I added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to create `form_data` from `request.POST`. You can create the form instance as `form1 = OneForm(request.POST, prefix=OneForm.Meta.model._meta.module_name)`.